# Proper way of convering 3 bytes Span to int

Tags: c#

I know, I can convert 3 bytes `Span` to byte array by converting each byte separately and combine into an integer. I can also concatenate 1-byte array with 3-bytes array converted from `Span` and use `BitConverter` class. These methods are old and well known, but I am considering if there is a better way for doing this, especially when using `Span` like this: `mySpan.Slice(10, 3)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that 3 bytes is a really awkward number, since there's no register size available of 3 bytes. One way would be to split it into 2 bytes and 1 byte, and `|` them together:

```
var arr = new byte[] { 5, 20, 10 };
var span = arr.AsSpan();

var val = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, ushort>(span.Slice(1))[0] << 16 | (span[0] << 8);
```

The assembly code generated by the JIT is just straight copies (`lea`) and shifts (`shr`) as expected, it's just the C# syntax that's a bit unwieldy.